# Navigation links point to URL containing anchor - Team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, url, anchor-tags

I want to be able to set a navigation link on a Team site to point to an anchor of a page. Something like this:

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxx/SitePages/Page1.aspx#section4
```

When I set the address to that when editing the navigation link, it strips out the `#section4` part of the URL after saving. Is there a way around this?

On a Communication site, it does NOT strip out the anchor tag from the URL in the top navigation, and it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **known issue** in SharePoint online modern experience.

You can follow this thread: [On page Anchors/bookmarks issue found](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/on-page-anchors-bookmarks-issue-found/m-p/809686)

I have also noticed that the anchored links work on other communication sites but not in **root** communication site top navigation.

Here are few things you can try/consider:

1. Create links to headings at the top of page & add page URL in site navigation --> Unfortunately it increases on additional click
2. Anchored links work in **Quick links web part** --> If possible create a quick links web part with anchored links on the site home page

Comment: Hi @Robby. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.